# Calling Silverlight Ria Services Design Issue

Tags: silverlight, interface, ria

I am trying to create a silverlight app that calls Ria WebServices, The Problem is i do not want Wire in (tightly couple) Ria Services into my ViewModel.

My idea was to Creata an interface wrapper. For example, if i wanted to use Ria Authentication Services i would simply create my own

```
public interface IMyAuthenticationService
 {
   void Login();
   void LoginCallBack(LoginResult result);
   event MyHandler LoginComplete()
 }
```

I could then use an implementation of the above interface in my viewmodel, for any Authentication Service. This would hopefully reduce the coupling to Ria services, since the above interface is generic.

I was wondering if you could provide me with any feedback on the above idea.  I'm not sure if this is a good way to approach the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you build a tightly coupled Models layer for use with your RIA services. If the Model layer is able to do all the work required through RIA, (it should be independantly testable) Then you can begin translating those operations through your View Model using an interface like you suggested; you could build the Models layer in a seperate Silverlight Library.

I successfully did exactly this with an enterprise solution, using TDD. I can provide more concrete code examples, if needed, but even a simple service call would have lots of classes. I can add some code samples.

Example, from the Bottom (the service) to the Top (the View):

We start with our very complex MultiplyService:

```
namespace StackOverflow.Tutorial.Web
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;

    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class MultiplyService : DomainService
    {
        [Invoke]
        public MultiplyDTO Multiply(MultiplyDTO input)
        {
            input.Answer = input.A * input.B;
            return input;
        }

        public class MultiplyDTO
        {
            public int Answer { get; set; }
            public int A { get; set; }
            public int B { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Which exposes some RIA magic to our Silverlight Client through a `MultiplyContext` class. We consume this class on the silverlight side in the Model thus:

```
using System;
using StackOverflow.Tutorial.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;

namespace StackOverflow.Tutorial.Models
{
    // This class is tightly coupled to 
    public class MultiplyServiceAgent : IMultiplyServiceAgent
    {
        public void Multiply(int a, int b, Action<int> callback)
        {
            MultiplyContext context = new MultiplyContext();
            MultiplyDTO question = new MultiplyDTO() { A = a, B = b };

            context.Multiply(question, (answer) =>
            {
                callback(answer.Value.Answer);
            }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I aslo include an interface `IMultiplyServiceAgent`:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
using StackOverflow.Tutorial.Web;

namespace StackOverflow.Tutorial.Models
{
    public interface IMultiplyServiceAgent
    {
        void Multiply(int a, int b, Action<int> callback);
    }
}
```

The Service Agent and Interface could be compiled into a seperate class library, if you wanted, then used by the View Model and View of your silverlight app, which are shown next. First the ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using StackOverflow.Tutorial.Models;

namespace StackOverflow.Tutorial.ViewModels
{
    public class MultiplyViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        IMultiplyServiceAgent agent = new MultiplyServiceAgent();

        public int A
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(AProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for A.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(int), typeof(MultiplyViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public int B
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(BProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for B.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(int), typeof(MultiplyViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public int Answer
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(AnswerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AnswerProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Answer.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AnswerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Answer", typeof(int), typeof(MultiplyViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public void Calculate()
        {
            agent.Multiply(this.A, this.B, (answer) =>
                {
                    this.Answer = answer;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflow.Tutorial.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox Name="txtA" Text="{Binding A, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBox Name="txtB" Text="{Binding B, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Button Name="btnCalculate" Content="Calculate" Click="btnCalculate_Click" />
        <TextBlock Name="txtAnswer" Text="{Binding Answer}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The View has a simple code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using StackOverflow.Tutorial.ViewModels;

namespace StackOverflow.Tutorial.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MultiplyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new MultiplyViewModel();
            this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewModel.Calculate();
        }
    }
}
```

So we see, in the examples above, that the Web Service and the Model of the silverlight app are tightly coupled, and integrated. The Model - with the ServiceAgent(s) and IService interfaces could be built in its own Silverlight Class Library, and shared with the various Silverlight apps in your enterprise solution. Since RIA really requires that the provider, and consumer be so tightly coupled, limiting this dependancy will prevent problems in the future, as you pointed out in the question.

Now that the provider and consumer are ready, the main Silverlight app wires up the Model through the ViewModel to the View. (ViewModels and Views are also tightly coupled, usually).

Comment: I'm not sure if i completley follow what are you saying.Are you suggesting that the flow of logic on the client side would be:  ViewModel -> TightlyCoupledModelLayer -> RIA Context Proxy.  If you wouldnt mind posting a very simple example it would be most appreciated

Comment: I'll work up a sample tomorrow, sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. The sample will contain some code for all layers from the Service backend - through the proxy - through the view-model - to the bound UI. The only part that would be tightly-coupled would be the "model" to the RIA service proxy.